# Couldn't connect to Postgresql running on VPS through Dbeaver

Tags: postgresql, ssh, psql, vps, dbeaver

I am new to postgresql and next js. I recently created a next js app with postgresql as backend. It is working fine in localhost. Then I bought a VPS, and installed postgres on it. It is working fine in that server. I tried accessing the server from my mac terminal through ssh.

It is working fine. I can also run psql commands on the terminal.

I tried to connect to the postgresql db via DBeaver. The SSH tunneling works fine, but the connection fails.

It is throwing an error "The connection attempt failed.
Connection reset
Connection reset"

The SSH is working fine, but I couldn't connect to postgres running on the remote server.

Comment: What is the DB log file about the connection attempt?  Have you tried setting up a tunnel manually (using ssh, not dbeaver, then connecting through the tunnel using psql?

Answer (score -2):

In the remote sever, navigate to **/etc/postgresql/{version}/main/**

Open **postgresql.conf** and search for 'listen_addresses'.

Remove the comment (if commented) and change it to '*' or comma separated ip addresses you want to allow connection from.

**listen_addresses = '*'**

Then save the file, and open **pg_hba.conf file**.

Scroll down till end and add this,

**host    <db_name>        <ip_addr>/32    scram-sha-256**

Replace db_name, user with the one you want. ip_addr should be the ip address of the remote vps.

PS: I encountered this error, and felt useful to be shared.

Comment: It is best to not listen on any public addresses/interfaces as that exposes the database to the public internet. Start over and get SSH port tunneling working.